# PIC18F reset cause WDT_FROM_SLEEP

Tags: pic, microchip

I use PIC18F6622 and PICC compiler.

I use the Watch Dog Timer to regularly wake from sleep mode. The data sheet states that watch dog fire during power-managed modes exits the mode and usually it works just fine.

However, sometimes I see an unexpected reset. Using PICC's **reset_cause()** I found that the reason is **WDT_FROM_SLEEP**. What does that mean? Why is it causing a reset instead of wake-up??

Thanks a lot,

Lkanab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interrupt event may have woken the PIC up, then the WDT probably overflowed during run mode, which would cause a watchdog reset.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering your MCPU into SLEEP mode.
In this mode the MCPU wait on event to wake-up form sleep.
You didn't explain what kind of events/interrupts are enabled before your program go into SLEEP mode.
Let say if you are waiting on OnPinChange (EEPROM write, ADC conversion ...) event and that is never heppend (or to late) so the Watch Dog time expire and reset the MCPU.

One solution: try to increase the Watch Dog Timer time interval.

Comment: I am waiting for several interrupts that may occur. At the same time, some jobs must be done regularly (say, every sec) and therefore the watch dog is set to fire and WAKE from sleep, it should NOT RESET the PIC.
I also quoted the data sheet which states that the watch-dog merely exit power managed mode (except when fired on "RUN" power-mode).
In 99.9% the WDT does "wake" the PIC from sleep. The WDT_FROM_SLEEP reset cause contradicts the data sheet. doesn't it??

Comment: @lkanab: Check DS39646B-page 312 (FIGURE 25-1:). The WDT should always Wake-up and also reset the MCPU after overflow!

Comment: I am sorry, but in this case I think you are wrong. The figure does indicate a reset but only when NOT in sleep. For clearing it out - check section 3.5.2 (page 47): "A WDT time-out will cause different actions depending on which power-managed mode the device is in when the time-out occurs. If the device is not executing code (all Idle modes and Sleep mode), the time-out will result in an exit from the
power-managed mode. If the device is executing code (all Run modes), the time-out will result in a WDT Reset"

Comment: @lkanab: Ahh... :) The reset_cause() function call (and action) must be at the beginning  of main() function. Is that how you did it? Check also: http://www.ccsinfo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27638&start=4